# Save UIView to iPad PhotoLibrary

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, uiimage, save, photolibrary

I'm creating an app where within a `UIView` subclass I have several `UIImageView`'s holding `UIImage`'s that the user has picked. I want to be able to allow the user to save the `UIView` to the PhotoLibrary so that those `UIImageView`'s are saved as a sort of collage within this `UIView`. Would I need to have a UIImageView in place of the `UIView` to allow the code to save the whole area? or would I be able to use the `UIView`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does what you want except storage:

```
-(UIImage *)takeScreeShotOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 748));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img; 
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, It's a starting point which is kinda what I was looking for, Thanks for your help!